How to send data between Docker containers on the same network
I have two docker containers on the same network. I want to send some data with POST and GET methods over HTTP. I am doing:
app = Flask(__name__)
is_processing = False  # Flag to indicate whether processing is ongoing
receiver_url = "http://172.18.0.2:8889/receive_data"  # Define the receiver URL 

and
app.run(port=8889)

on the sender container I am doing:
def send_data_to_receiver(data):
    receiver_url = "http://172.18.0.2:8889/receive_data"
    data_serializable = [x.tolist() for x in data]
    response = requests.post(receiver_url, json=data_serializable)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Data sent successfully to receiver notebook")
    else:
        print("Failed to send data to receiver notebook")

The above works successfully between jupyter notebooks, however when I am trying to add them in docker containers I get the following error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.18.0.2', port=8889): Max retries exceeded with url: /receive_data (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc750529cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

What is wrong with my setup?

Your question isn't a minimal repro of your issue making it more difficult to help. But, the error suggests the server isn't on 172.18.0.2:8889. When you run containers, you can --name=foo them and, if they're on the same network, then you can use this name to address them. Try running the server --name=foo and then, with your client use receiver_url = "http://foo:8889/receive_data.

do u have a docker-compose file? pls post that; if not, I would certainly suggest making one. It makes docker networking much easier and more approachable. Instead of using IP addressed, you can just use the name of the service that you defined.

Do you need app.run(port=8889, host='0.0.0.0') as in Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues?  Without that host='0.0.0.0' option, the Flask server won't be reachable from outside its own container.
